# How do I take a string and turn it into a list using SCALA?

Tags: string, list, scala

I am brand new to Scala and having a tough time figuring this out.

I have a string like this:

```
a = "The dog crossed the street"
```

I want to create a list that looks like below:

```
a = List("The","dog","crossed","the","street")
```

I tried doing this using .split(" ") and then returning that, but it seems to do nothing and returns the same string. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/P7RSaSzOSPGFyTTtom1K8A

Answer (score 1):

1. It's safer to `split()` on one-or-more whitespace characters, just in case there are any tabs or adjacent spaces in the mix.
2. `split()` returns an `Array` so if you want a `List` you'll need to convert it.

```
"The dog\tcrossed\nthe      street".split("\\s+").toList
//res0: List[String] = List(The, dog, crossed, the, street)
```